# Sending HTTP post requests

Tags: micropython

I am using a micropython firmware **version** `esp8266-20190125-v1.10.bin` for `esp8266mod`. I accessed REPL prompt via a wired connection using picocom and connected the device to my home wifi. I was trying to send some HTTP post requests using urequests.

`import urequests
 response = urequests.post('http://lakshmick.pythonanywhere.com/savedata', data = {'string': 'posting from micropython'})`

**I got some error like this:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "urequests.py", line 115, in post
    File "urequests.py", line 100, in request
    File "urequests.py", line 79, in request
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
```

**Does it require any additional configuration procedures before importing urequests?**

Answer (score 4):

You need to **serialize** the data into a string before sending it:

```
myPostedData = {'YYYY' : 100}
res = urequest.post('https://XXX.amazonaws.com/XXX/XXX', data=json.dumps(myPostedData))
jsonresults = json.loads(res.content)
```

Comment: @nekomatic No, `data=json.dumps(myPostedData)` `json.dumps` does what @Phil states, serialize's the data.

Comment: @wildernessfamily it looks like I posted the comment first and then edited the answer, which made my comment obsolete (see the edit history). Thanks for pointing out the potential confusion! I've deleted the original comment now.